Why wouldnt you use a larger second stage resistor in a passive bandpass?
I am building a simple passive RC bandpass filter.  I would like to pass frequencies between 500Hz and 20kHz.  This filter is driven by a source with an output impedance of 100 ohms.
I chose R1 (first stage) to be 1k to prevent loading, and then I chose R2 (second stage) to be 100x that.  My output was as expected, a decent pass band with my corner frequencies where I planned.


Here is my question.  Whenever I read about these filters online, the two resistors are the same value.  But when I use 1k for the second stage (and adjust my capacitor to get the same frequency), the entire pass band is attenuated by more than 1 dB.  Why would a circuit use equivalent resistors?  Is is preferred to my solution?
Is the answer that the lower output impedance is more important than a 1dB signal loss?

Among other reasons, duplicating a resistor can take advantage of economies of scale.

$R_2$ should not change your mid-band attenuation in this testbench. You are doing something wrong.

I'd go for something less extreme, like a 10:1 ratio. The question you asked is moot though, as little to no serious engineering is done with RC filters like this. Almost any practical application needs higher orders or narrower stopbands.


Is the answer that the lower output impedance is more important than a 1dB signal loss?

In the real world, yes, output impedance and input impedance are design constraints the more you increase the impedance in the filter the less power you have at the next stage, and so the more you need to amplify.

The mid-band attenuation depends on your loss budget or specs for both voltage, power loss, output impedance and load variations.
One might consider writing down all their design specs or expectations they consider important first before choosing an implementation.
All that matters is that it meets all the "customer's" expectations. But you get to write or review the design specs usually, implement the design and validate the results (DVT).

To avoid the attenuation that similar R1 and R2 would cause, the second stage must not excessively load the first, which you do achieve by making R2 very large, 100kΩ. There are two big consequences to this:

Output impedance is very high now, anything you attach with an input impedance under, say, 1MΩ is going to both attenuate the signal, and alter the cut-off frequency.

A large R2 necessitates a commensurately small C2 of 80pF. Parasitic capacitances such as PCB trace capacitance and amplifier input capacitance, which can all easily amount to tens of picofarads, are comparable with 80pF, and will severely influence cut-off frequency.


